# Merging form and fieldset doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, forms, fieldset

I've a `<form>` to upload an image and a `<fieldset>` to send some data using AJAX, they both work fine, but my problem happens when I try to merge them in one form. I'm using Node.JS server.

**Upload `<form>`:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
 <input type="file" name="upl"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

**Node.JS router upload post:**

```
router.post('/upload', upload, function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(204).end();

});
```

**`<fieldset>`:**

```
<div id="addAdv">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTimeStamp">Time</label>
    <input id="inputTimeStamp" type="text" class="form-control"/><br/>
    <label for="inputURL">URL</label>
    <input id="inputURL" type="url"/><br/>
    <button id="btnAddAdv" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Node.Js router data post:**

```
router.post('/addadv', function(req, res) {

    Feed.collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#btnAddAdv').on('click', addAdv);

function addAdv(event) {
.....
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: newUser,
    url: '/addadv',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function( response )...}
```

**Let's try to merge them:**

```
<div id="addAdv">
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="upl"/>
    <label for="inputTimeStamp">Time</label>
    <input id="inputTimeStamp" type="text" class="form-control"/><br/>
    <label for="inputURL">URL</label>
    <input id="inputURL" type="url"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnAddAdv" value="Send"/>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

**Also tried:**

```
<button id="btnAddAdv" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're submitting your merged form via the submit button and not via XHR, then you need to add `name` attributes for your non-file fields, otherwise the browser will not send them to the server.

Comment: I added name for all other inputs, still not working

Comment: Did you verify that the fields are being sent after adding the `name` attributes by using your browser's web developer tools' network tab?